# F# fails to install on MonoDevelop 2.8 for Mac

Tags: macos, f#, mono, monodevelop

I foolishly upgraded my MonoDevelop to 2.8 on my Mac, and the F# binding now fails to install from the http://functional-variations.net/addin repo - it needs v2.4 and MonoDevelop has moved to v2.6 of the Core and Ide. Does anyone know how I can get MonoDevelop 2.8 to play nicely with F#, or how I should roll back?

Comment: the latest version is here : https://github.com/fsharp/fsharpbinding , seems like there is nothing about MD 2.8

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I tried to install *FSharpBinding* to *MonoDevelop* 2.8 or 2.6 and didn't succeed. The reason is that *FSharpBinding* is obsolete and incompatible with newest versions of *MonoDevelop* (see detailed discussions [here](http://groups.google.com/group/fsharp-opensource/browse_thread/thread/26612c58a0f02926)). So first remove *MonoDevelop* 2.8 or 2.6 and their associated files, and install *MonoDevelop* 2.4.2.

You didn't mention versions of *FSharp* and *Mono*. Some old versions work fine with *FSharpBinding* from http://functional-variations.net/addin repo. However, when I tried to install *Mono 2.10.x* which includes F# compilers making it easier to set up F# development environment,  *FSharpBinding* didn't work again. I followed the suggestion by above discussion and install *FSharpBinding* from source, and it's working ok. So the current configuration in my Mac is *MonoDevelop 2.4.2*, *Mono 2.10.x/ FSharp 2.0* and *FSharpBinding* compiled from source.

You can find the detailed guideline [here](http://chrismarinos.com/f-on-ubuntu-linux-with-mono-and-monodevelop/) about how to install the whole F# development environment (including *FSharpBinding*) from source.

**UPDATE**:

[FSharpBinding](http://addins.monodevelop.com/Project/Index/48) has been [released for MonoDevelop 3.0](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups#!topic/fsharp-opensource/F30aSKbFYQg). Install MonoDevelop 3.0 (which requires Mono 2.10.9 onwards) and you can install FSharpBinding via Add-In Manager.

Comment: Thanks, what a pity. The FSharpBinding was most useful, shame that it can't keep up with the newer releases.

Comment: This answer helped a lot. If you need more detailed instructions, check out http://answerqi.com/asq/259/answermail/61/how-do-i-set-up-monodevelop-to-work-with-f-on-mac-os

Comment: @JamieForrest: The instructions there are detailed but a bit redundant. You don't need to install a separate F# package since F# is included in Mono 2.10.9.

Comment: In my case for whatever reason fsharpc wasn't installed after installing Mono 2.10.9 from this installer: http://www.go-mono.com/mono-downloads/download.html